# Shortcut to connect to a password protected server

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

Using the syntax

```
steam://connect/IP:PORT
```

Can I add a server password? (For csgo if it helps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.**

`steam://connect/ip:port/password`

You can actually do a lot more than that and the game in question isn't relevant to that (as long as it's for Steam that is), since it's the *Steam browser protocol* we're talking about. You could connect to any supported game's servers.

See [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol) for more options.